# convert flat json object into hierarchical xml

Tags: javascript, json, xml, underscore.js, lodash

I have json object like this:

```
    var client = {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "John Doe",
  "name2": "Jane Doe",
  "email": "John@test.com",
  "phone": "+1-306-5555555",
  "phoneType": "Home",
  "phone2": "+1-306-5556666",
  "phone2Type": "Business",
  "gender": "Male",
  "address": "1000 Center AVE",
  "postCode": "S7J 1P3",
  "city": "Saskatoon",
  "province": "SK",
  "country": "CA",
  "dob": "1990-12-11T02:00:00.000Z",
  "maritalStatus": "Single",
  "occupation": "Software Developer",
  "createdAt": "2015-12-07T08:14:21.000Z",
  "updatedAt": "2016-01-19T13:35:10.000Z"
};
```

Which I want to convert into XML, this isn't a problem I know there great library like x2js that can do that for me.

My problem is xml file, need to follow a standard like this:

```
   <GeneralPartyInfo>
<NameInfo>
    <PersonName>
        <Surname>Doe </Surname>
        <GivenName>John</GivenName>
    </PersonName>
    <SupplementaryNameInfo>
        <SupplementaryName>Jane Doe</SupplementaryName>
    </SupplementaryNameInfo>
</NameInfo>
<Addr>
    <DetailAddr>
        <StreetName>Centre</StreetName>
        <StreetNumber>1000</StreetNumber>
        <csio:StreetTypeCd>AVE</csio:StreetTypeCd>
    </DetailAddr>
    <City>Saskatoon</City>
    <StateProvCd>SK</StateProvCd>
    <PostalCode>S7J 1P3</PostalCode>
    <CountryCd>CA</CountryCd>
</Addr>
<Communications>
    <PhoneInfo>
        <PhoneTypeCd>Phone</PhoneTypeCd>
        <CommunicationUseCd>Home</CommunicationUseCd>
        <PhoneNumber>+1-306-5555555</PhoneNumber>
    </PhoneInfo>
    <PhoneInfo>
        <PhoneTypeCd>Phone</PhoneTypeCd>
        <CommunicationUseCd>Business</CommunicationUseCd>
        <PhoneNumber>+1-306-5556666</PhoneNumber>
    </PhoneInfo>
</Communications>
```

you can xml is nested while my json isn't, not mention name need to spliced to firstName and lastName and be inside PersonName which is child of NameInfo, and GeneralPartyInfo be the root parent (same thing for the address).

there two problems I have, the first one is a missing tags for example firstname is inside PersonName which inside  NameInfo which inside GeneralPartyInfo  and I can't do this

```
  var firstName = client.name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
  var lastName =  client.name.split(' ').slice(-1).join(' ');
  delete client.name;

client.PersonName.push({
        GiveName: firstName,
        Surname: lastName,
});
```

because JSON is an object  not an array, it requires for me to convert JSON into an array (which is not recommended by other professionals here in SO), or I can save each one (Name, address, communication) into it separate json object then concat all of them together abdthe only way I found in SO to add parent json object was like this

```
  var obj = {fistName: client.name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' '), lastName: client.name.split(' ').slice(-1).join(' ');};
     var obj2 = { "PersonName" : obj };
     var obj3 = { "NameInfo" : obj2 };
```

my second problem is find a way to replace keys for example I want to replace postcode to PostalCode or phoneType to CommunicationUseCd

or just do it this way

```
    var xml =  "<GeneralPartyInfo><NameInfo><PersonName>
   <Surname>" + client.name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' '); + "</Surname>
   <GivenName>"+client.name.split(' ').slice(-1).join(' ')+"</GivenName>"
```

but this solution is tedious, not efficient and doesn't look pretty and I'm looking more for stability and cleanliness of code.

For example How can I  manipulate a json object to add parent to selected elements then I can replace keys through list that have keys to be replaced for example.

```
 var translationObj = {
      "firstName": "GivenName",
      "lastName": "PersonName", 
    }
```

PS: I have lodash/underscore installed so a solution using underscore would be great.

Comment: You should add more of the code you have tried to use. Currently this question is in the category *"implement this specification for me"*, which is not a good category of questions. Improve it by turning it into a *"I have tried this and that but I have problems with this particular thing"* category question.

Comment: @Tomalak I have edited the question, is that improved enough or do I have to change or add something else.

Comment: I see. You must never build XML this way. I mean it. This will break during run-time and it's wide open for injection attacks. Use a DOM to build XML. (Apart from that, I'm still not sure what the actual question is here.)